# Hibernate - Add member entity instance by ID

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I have an entity of type A with a referenced member entity of type B.
I want to insert a relationship between an instance of A to an existing instance of B without having to fetch B.

Is there a way to do it simply by ID? Something like:

> B mockB = new B();
>
> mockB.id = "id_persisted_b";
>
> instanceA.setB(mockB);

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA you can use `EntityManager.getReference()` to obatin a proxy of the object without fetching all the fields, e.g.:

```
B mockB = entityManager.getReference(B.class, "id_persisted_b");
instanceA.setB(mockB);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Fetch type LAZY hibernate will not load the object, it will load only a reference to it when you need. Is like having just the PrimaryKey of the element. It does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy fetching decides whether to load child objects while loading the Parent Object. You need to do this setting respective hibernate mapping file of the parent class.

Lazy = true (means not to load child). By default the lazy loading of the child objects is true.